# Create a word document (from excel) with a title, a paragraph, a table, a paragraph, a text, a paragraph, a table, a paragraph and a text

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a word document from excel.
I think I can do it, but to fill the word document with what I want (a title, an empty paragraph, a table... wherever I want) give me some headache. I certainly don't master the word-vba, I find excel-vba easier.
Below is my horrible code, but if you can give me a piece of code doing what is describe in the title, it could be a good starting point for me.

```
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim objRange As Object
    Dim objTable As Object
    Dim txtword As String
    '-----------------------
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    Set objRange = objDoc.Content 'Range
    '-----------------------
    txtword = "Something"
    With objRange
        .Text = txtword & vbCr & vbCr 'add the paragraph break at the end of the text string
        .Collapse Direction:=0
    End With
    Set objTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(objRange, 2, 8)
    objTable.Borders.Enable = True
    
    
    objRange.Text = txtword & vbCr & vbCr
    objRange.Collapse Direction:=0
    
    
    ' From direct Macro:
    'objRange.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=3
    'objRange.TypeParagraph
    'objRange.TypeText Text:="Text"
    'objRange.TypeParagraph

    
    ' HOW TO GET OUT OF THIS TABLE????
    
    
    'objRange.Text = "" & vbCr
    'Set objRange = objDoc.Content
    'objRange.Collapse Direction:=0
    objDoc.Tables.Add Range:=objRange, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=2
    
    '---------------------
    Set objTable = Nothing
    Set objRange = Nothing
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing
```

Comment: Use `objDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range` and you’ll have no difficulty getting beyond the table.

Comment: Better still, use a Word **Template** with all the boilerplate content *in-situ*.

Comment: Empty paragraphs are problematic in Word although common. If you can, use paragraph spacing instead. Empty paragraphs make for formatting problems.

Comment: Thanks Timothy, but objDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range didn't work for me. The txtWord is added in the first cell of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with stop using late binding when working across Office applications. There are no advantages to this approach but lots of disadvantages. Instead write your code using the oldest version of Office you need/intend to support.

Secondly, use `objDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range` and you’ll have no difficulty building your document.

Thirdly, you should use Styles to format your document so that you can identify which text is a heading, etc. You need to remember to always use the Normal style when inserting tables to enable the correct functioning of table styles, but for other text you should use a Style where the name describes its purpose, i.e. Body Text.

Ideally you would create a template for the type of document you are creating containing any standard content and with all the styles defined as you want them. You can then either go old school and use bookmarks to act as placeholders for text or use content controls.

```
Sub CreateWordDoc()
   Dim wdApp As Word.Application
   Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
   Dim wdTable As Word.Table
   Dim quitWord As Boolean
   Dim txtword As String
   '-----------------------
   On Error Resume Next
   Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
   If Err Then
      'Word wasn't already running so create a new instance of MS Word
      Err.Clear
      Set wdApp = New Word.Application
      If Err Then
         MsgBox "Microsoft Word not installed"
         Exit Sub
      Else
         'as Word wasn't already open set flag to show Word needs to be shut down
         'and make application visible
         quitWord = True
         wdApp.Visible = True
      End If
   End If
   'clear error stack and reset error handling
   On Error GoTo 0
   Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
   '-----------------------
   txtword = "Something"
   With wdDoc.Content
      .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = txtword & vbCr & vbCr 'add the paragraph break at the end of the text string
      .Paragraphs.First.Style = wdStyleHeading1
      Set wdTable = wdDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=.Paragraphs.Last.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=8)
      wdTable.Borders.Enable = True
    
      With .Paragraphs.Last.Range
         .Style = wdStyleBodyText
         .Text = vbCr & txtword & vbCr
      End With
      .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Style = wdStyleNormal
      Set wdTable = wdDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=.Paragraphs.Last.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=2)
      wdTable.Borders.Enable = True
      With .Paragraphs.Last.Range
         .Style = wdStyleBodyText
         .Text = vbCr & txtword
      End With
   End With
   wdDoc.SaveAs2 "Full path and filename"
   '---------------------
   If quitWord Then wdApp.Quit
   Set wdTable = Nothing
   Set wdDoc = Nothing
   Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start for me. It works well. And now, I understand the comment of macropod about the Word Template as you had also highlighted the use of a Word Template. I won't use "object" as well, thanks again for all your advices.